# writing the ladder if equality statements in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I know i can do this in django template

```
ifequal "this"
  ...//
else
  ...//
endifequal
```

but how do i write this

```
ifequal "this"
  ..//
elseifequal "this"
  ...//
else
  ....
```

is there a elegant way to achieve this in django ?

Answer (score 2):

Django templates support the Python-like `elif` tag. For example:

```
{% if this == True %}
  Yes!
{% elif this == False %}
  No!
{% else %}
  What?
{% endif %}
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if

The documentation is very easy to find, so I suggest you read up on that.

Comment: this is good, but i was looking for something like elseifequal since other expressions are using ifequal tag.

Comment: The `ifequal` tag was deprecated as far back as Django 1.2. You really should be using the much more powerful and consistent `if ... ==` tag. Update the rest of your code to that effect as well. Where did you find an example of the `ifequal` tag?
 
Edit: I just see that is was not officially deprecated, but you would rarely see it. As the official documentation states: "There’s really no reason to use {% ifequal %} or {% ifnotequal %} anymore, unless you’re the nostalgic type."

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
{% ifequal p.gender "M" %}
Bloke
{% else %}
Sheila
{% endifequal %}
```

The ifequal tag determines if two arguments are equal. The arguments can be either
variables or hard-coded strings. If the arguments match, the template engine renders the
code inside the ifequal block. You need to add an endifequal tag to end the block.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal